# In Terraform, how can I assign into a variable a list of strings from another file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-waf, hashicorp

I'd like to test if it's possible assigning a list of strings from a txt file to a terraform variable.

I have a file named ip_adresses.txt with something like this:

```
["1.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8", ..., "n"]
```

This txt is constantly changing with different IP addresses, I'd like to have this values into a terraform resource of WAF IP_Set, which it requires an argument of [addresses](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_ip_set#addresses) as an array of strings.

I tried setting up my variable like this, giving the value of the variable the path of my file, which both are at the same directory level:

```
variable "addresses_ipv4" {
  default = "ip_adresses.txt"
}
```

and in my resource:

```
addresses = file(var.addresses_ipv4)
```

But I got this Error Message:

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "addresses": set of string required.
```

How can I tell terraform that I want to use the content in my file, which is an array of strings, as the variable for that needed list?

Answer (score 2):

Your actual code return `"[\"1.1.1.1\", \"8.8.8.8\"]"`, you have to use `jsondecode` like this:

```
addresses = jsondecode(file(var.addresses_ipv4))
```

This will parse your JSON in your file and return an array of strings.

Output example

```
[
  "1.1.1.1",
  "8.8.8.8",
]
```

Beside the format of the IPs you have in your txt are not correct, [aws_wafv2_ip_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_ip_set#addresses) waiting a format like this: `"1.1.1.1/32"` not just `"1.1.1.1"`

Comment: Hi @Youcef Laidani, thanks for the reply, after trying this I got the same error output in the console, but not sure about what you mention that my code returns a JSON, because my txt file is just a single line.

Comment: No, this is not possible, I tried my code many times and it works with `jsondecode`, make sure that your file holds a correct JSON

Comment: @YoucefLAIDANI's answer is correct. Just wanted to note that you can't do ```
default = "ip_adresses.txt"
```
and expect the default to be the contents of that file. You are telling it the default is literally the string "ip_adresses.txt".